# WinJS webpage inside webview returns 0x80070005 on ajax call that uses cors

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-8.1, winjs

We have a WinJS apps that shows a web site inside a WebView control, the WebPage loads fine however every ajax call fails with **0x80070005 Access is denied error**. We tried adding "*Internet (Client)*", "*Internet (Client/Server)*" and "*Private Networks*" capabilities to the app without success.

The calls use **CORS** to allow calling multiple domains, the site **is working fine on every desktop browser**, even on IE inside Modern environment. However, when the site is running inside the WebView control, only the preflight request runs, despite the server being responding with status code 200, the real request is never being sent.

We can see this using Fiddler, here is the preflight request:

```
OPTIONS /Queries/QueryContentAreas/GetAvaliableContentAreas HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Origin: https://myapp.demo.es
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, authorization
UA-CPU: AMD64
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64; Trident/7.0; MSAppHost/2.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Host: myappapi.demo.es
Content-Length: 0
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

And here is the server's response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://myapp.demo.es
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: authorization
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 29 May 2014 16:32:56 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

In Visual Studio this access denied error appears:

```
SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Error de red 0x80070005, Acceso denegado.
File: demo
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you ever figured this out or not, but I'm running into something similar.

Based on [Features and restrictions by context (HTML)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465373.aspx) it seems like since the app is inside the web context (because it's in a WebView) cross-domain XHR requests are not allowed.